# Cannot reinstall grub after use of testdisk

Tags: partitioning, uefi, grub-efi, reinstall, data-loss

I have 2 OS on my laptop: Windows and Linux. Once there was no space left on Linux, and, as a result, my important file was erased. I have tried to restore it using testdisk, but instead of after rebooting I've got a black screen with the text "Minimal bash-like line is supported".

I've tried to reinstall grub using [this paper (itsfoss)](https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/) and [this paper (fosslinux)](https://www.fosslinux.com/115031/troubleshoot-boot-problems-by-reinstalling-grub-on-linux.htm), but unsuccessfully, also I've tried to use boot-repair, but boot-repair hasn't given me option "recommended repair".

[This is](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/83v9mvh2ns/) info generated by boot-repair.
My sequence of actions in reinstalling grub:

```
    sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p4 /mnt/
    sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/boot/efi
    sudo apt install grub-efi efibootmgr
    sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --bootloader-id=ubuntu  --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi
```

Command

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Gives me an error

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

(this is from fosslinux)

[Image of Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvm7J.png)

Is there a way to reinstall grub and give all my files in Linux and Windows back?

Comment: I mean, I' was working on important file in VSCode, I've tried to save the file, but Linux told me that he can't save the file because the space on device ended. I decided to switch off my laptop, and, after rebooting, I found out that my file was empty. VSCode didn't suggest me to restore the file, ctrl+Z didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode unsaved files location](https://superuser.com/questions/1225368/visual-studio-code-unsaved-files-location). However, if there was no storage space available, then it's possible that nothing could be saved by VSCode.

Comment: I think, it'd have been an answer if I hadn't run testdisk, but now the problem is much more serious, because my Grub has crashed, and I can't even load Ubuntu. But if I recover all my files, I will use this solution, thanks for providing it.

Comment: Most systems only like one ESP - efi system partition per drive. And you have two p2 & p3. Each may have different boot files(not shown), but p2's Windows boot goes to a partition that does not exist. Did you delete Windows with Linux install? And p3 is FAT16 which supposedly may work, but FAT32 is the standard for last 10 years.

Comment: No, I didn't delete Windows. Firstly, there had been Windows on laptop, after that I installed Linux. I've used both OS for about 2.5 years.

Comment: Both partitions had had FAT16 filesystem before I used GParted, and then I reformatted p2 into FAT32. As I remember, partitions were FAT32 before use of testdisk. May be, testdisk have changed them.